# In client-server communication, why server always respond (i.e.http Response) to user in HTML format?

Tags: client-server, httpclient

In client-server communication, why server always respond (i.e. Http Response) to user in HTML format and not in any other format?

Comment: If you press F12 in the browser then go to the network tab, you should see many requests in a few differents formats : HTML, CSS, JSON... Can you clarify what you mean exactly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In HTTP Client-Server communication, it is possible to do a content-negotiation if the server supports different styles of responses like XML, JSON or TXT other than plain old HTTP responses. All that the client has to do is to send the desired format in Accept headers that is sent in the HTTP request. This is one of the core concepts of RESTful interface envisioned by Roy Fielding.